# When will all 45 billion coins be in circulation?

Tags: ada, coin

I cannot find any accurate information with what speed and based on what formula the coins which are not in circulation will be in circulation and when (approximately) all coins will be in circulation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The formula is quite complex, but at a high level it's an exponential decay like Bitcoin.

Up to 0.3% of the remaining reserves may be mined at each epoch (5 days), however it depends on various factors such as how many blocks were mined, so currently the average is closer to 0.2% per epoch.

At 0.2% per epoch, that corresponds to 13.59% of remaining reserves mined every year:

```
1 - (1 - 0.002)^(365/5) = 0.1359
```

So assuming 0.2% per epoch, it would take roughly 16 years (from genesis) for 90% of the supply to be in circulation, and 32 years for 99% to be in circulation.

Comment: So each year the percentage of minted coins is less because the transactions are more (they cover the rewards for the SPOs and the delegators)?

Comment: This is just what's coming from the reserve, transaction fees are in addition to that and are independent AFAIK.